# React Native Fire Base Notification listener

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, android-notifications

In react native firebase notification what happens if I don't stop the listener on unmount and the user fully closes the app? Does this keep a process running event though the app was shutdown?.

Comment: If the app is shut down the process should be stopped. however it is a memory leak when you don’t remove listeners when components are unmounted. It’s good practice to remove them once they are no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I found a work around to my problem. originally I was having the issue of the notification popping up twice when entering the app because I got from single screen to tab base. so I though just leaving the listener open instead of stopping it when switching from single to tab, but the work around is to check for the notification ID and if it equals the last notification ID than I don't display it.